# Flutter SDK Directory related issue

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

[image: Screenshot link]

Facing Issue while installing flutter sdk to android studio, it shows file called flutter already installed.
Kindly check screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

it says a file named flutter already exists... delete that file. or use it... or you can move it to other location first to work it out.